# Natural gas line repair

Tags: natural-gas

I have a natural gas line that runs from my meter across a creek and up to my home, we just recently had some severe flooding and the water eroded the creek bank and ripped apart my gas line, the creek is about 15ft wide and 2ft deep. Looking for new ideas to keep this problem from happening again.

Comment: Can you check if you can have it buried under the creek?  Sounds like it was just placed over the creek.

Comment: No it wasn't buried by the previous home owner, they ran the line through a 2 inch metal pipe used a sleeve and laid in the creek with rocks and whatever else laid on top of it

Comment: I have lived here for almost 10 years and have had some bad flooding before and no issues until now

Comment: My old house had a dry basement for years.  We decided to finish it.  Guess what happen the next year.

Comment: When you say "ripped apart", does that mean you now have an active gas leak? I hope you called the gas company to get this shut off! I would _think_ that it might be on them to get this repaired, but it may depend on whether the break is on your side of the meter or theirs. Either way, they would be the ones to talk to for an authoritative answer that meets your local code requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Unusual high, fast water can be an erosion problem for oil and gas production lines also. I suggest putting the casing (outer pipe) deeper. There are contractors that will drill under a creek ( or road, etc.) and pull casing through. There is a potential problem with cathodic protection (the gas company likely has cathodic protection on the line). If the failed gas line did not show external corrosion, it may not be a problem in this particular location. An oil company will seal each end of the casing ( with gas line inside) and fill the annulus with oil to prevent corrosion. This can be a complicated situation for cathodic protection. I suggest talking to the gas company for their recommendations.

Comment: Its a plastic line, the previous home owner just slid the plastic line through a metal line as a protective sleeve

Comment: "I suggest talking to the gas company for their recommendations." +100!!

Comment: Plastic in a steel casing sounds good.